# Android Studio 2.2.1 Gradle Sync NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-studio-2.2

I have installed android studio 2.2 and created new project but gradle sync failed every time and getting following exception.

```
Error:Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:3813)
at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:3800)
at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtilRt.doCreateTempFile(FileUtilRt.java:399)
at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtilRt.createTempFile(FileUtilRt.java:361)
at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtilRt.createTempFile(FileUtilRt.java:341)
at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtilRt.createTempFile(FileUtilRt.java:334)
at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtil.createTempFile(FileUtil.java:1479)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.util.GradleUtil.addInitScriptCommandLineOption(GradleUtil.java:1064)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.util.GradleUtil.addLocalMavenRepoInitScriptCommandLineOption(GradleUtil.java:1057)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.util.GradleUtil.addLocalMavenRepoInitScriptCommandLineOption(GradleUtil.java:1023)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.getExtraCommandLineArgs(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:345)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:175)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$300(GradleProjectResolver.java:73)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:768)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:752)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:238)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:112)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:73)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:51)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:138)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:124)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:419)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:500)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:369)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Anyone faced same issue or found any solution ?

Comment: tried running as admin? I know it seems kind of obvious

Comment: Thanks, running as administrator solved the issue.

Comment: What is the solution if i'm not admin user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @keddy 1201 his comment saved my life. I have tried uninstalling studio and java sdk and then reinstalled again couple of times with previous version and with also new versions.

**Tried running studio as administrator solved the problem**

Comment: Allowing non-administrators to access temp folder would be a solution. Granting admin rights to an app when it does not need them for work sounds like a workaround and potential security threat.

Comment: My current user was already Admin. But i have to explicitly run it again as Administrator to solve the problem.

Comment: User is admin = user is member of Administrators user group. If you found out why you need to run it as administrator, you wouldnt have to run it as administrator. Since nobody else has this problem, you may have misconfigured access rights to parts of your file system and thats the real problem. Granting admin rights is a workaround. Fixing access rights is the real solution.

Comment: What is the solution if i'm not admin user.

Answer (score 0):

Though the question has an accepted answer, but in my case with opening Android Studio 2.2.1 (though not actually only Gradle Sync), I opened the `bin/idea.properties` file inside the `android-studio` installation folder and had inserted the following line as suggested in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hXTzIbaQ9r8):

```
disable.android.first.run=true
```

Then restarting Android-Studio has solved the `NullPointerException`.