# Gradle 'APP' project refresh failed Cause:Java.Lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

sincerely, I tried almost EVERYTHING that is on the internet.Even not directly related to this specific problem.This problem is happening in Android Studio even before I Installed the latest version.I was about a month without working in Android Studio.The only thing related to Gradle that I messed with, was adding the LibGDX to Eclipse for a University work.I may be talking nonsense, but a think the problem appeared after that, because I had to install the SDK for Eclipse and this may be caused the issue.

When I open Android, I can't build my apk.So I made several changes to the app and noticed that nothing changed.So I Looked to the Gradle build and saw:

*Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution. Cause: unknown.*

in Gradle Sync I got:

> Gradle 'BluetoothConnector' project refresh failed

So I tried:[PrintScreen of the Android Studio error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FTXl.png)

> ◘Updating Android Studio
>
> ◘Turning off Oflline mode.
>
> ◘Reinstalling(I did it several times with false hopes) every  thing
>   related to Java(JDK,Java,JRE,Eclipse,Android Studio).
>
> ◘Checked the project Structure, add Dependecies entries.
>
> ◘Invalidade Cache/Restart
>
> ◘Export/Reimport.

So as you fellow programmers can see, I'm kind of struggling hard with this problem.Before I ask a question, a very long battle has already been going on for quite a while.And I simply don't know what else to do.

*I tried starting a new application, and the same refresh error appears. All my other apps as well.*

Comment: Looks like a strange bug in the startup/first-run part of IntelliJ: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39936273/1531971

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunely the only solution was a clean formating of the PC.I have no Idea what caused this, but it was the only thing left to do.And it worked.If Anyone come across this issue, that's really what do to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me.
1. Change `compile` to `implementation` or `api` (As `compile` is now deprecated)
2. Clean the project

Check following links for more details:
[Gradle Project refresh failed error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45647518/gradle-project-refresh-failed-error)
[Use the new dependency configurations](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations)