# Gradle Project refresh failed error

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Today i got an update for my Canary Android studio and I have updated my android studio from 3.0 Canary 9 to 3.0 beta 2, and it wanted to upgrade the Gradle version from `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha9` to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta2` after upgrading it, i'm getting this error:

```
Error:Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:98)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildOutput.getOutputPath(BuildOutput.java:222)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildOutputs.lambda$load$2(BuildOutputs.java:243)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1376)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildOutputs.load(BuildOutputs.java:245)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildOutputs.load(BuildOutputs.java:184)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildOutputs.load(BuildOutputs.java:140)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.BuildOutputsSupplier.lambda$get$1(BuildOutputsSupplier.java:55)
at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.forEach(ImmutableList.java:397)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.BuildOutputsSupplier.get(BuildOutputsSupplier.java:50)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.BuildOutputsSupplier.get(BuildOutputsSupplier.java:35)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.AndroidArtifactImpl.getOutputs(AndroidArtifactImpl.java:134)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$ReflectionMethodInvoker.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:592)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$AdaptingMethodInvoker.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:397)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$PropertyCachingMethodInvoker.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:625)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$SafeMethodInvoker.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:647)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$SupportedPropertyInvoker.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:670)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$InvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:356)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy182.getOutputs(Unknown Source)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeAndroidArtifactImpl.<init>(IdeAndroidArtifactImpl.java:57)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeVariantImpl.lambda$new$1(IdeVariantImpl.java:63)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.ModelCache.lambda$computeIfAbsent$0(ModelCache.java:31)
at java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1126)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.ModelCache.computeIfAbsent(ModelCache.java:31)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeModel.copy(IdeModel.java:74)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeVariantImpl.<init>(IdeVariantImpl.java:62)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeAndroidProjectImpl.lambda$new$4(IdeAndroidProjectImpl.java:88)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.ModelCache.lambda$computeIfAbsent$0(ModelCache.java:31)
at java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1126)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.ModelCache.computeIfAbsent(ModelCache.java:31)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeModel.copy(IdeModel.java:74)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeAndroidProjectImpl.<init>(IdeAndroidProjectImpl.java:87)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeAndroidProjectImpl.<init>(IdeAndroidProjectImpl.java:68)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.AndroidModuleModel.<init>(AndroidModuleModel.java:131)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.populateModuleContentRoots(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:214)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.populateModuleContentRoots(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:103)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:366)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$200(GradleProjectResolver.java:79)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:902)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:886)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:218)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:139)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:79)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.lambda$resolveProjectInfo$0(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:45)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:66)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:139)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:125)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:388)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$5.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:445)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:726)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:176)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:556)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:501)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:163)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:137)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

and these are my Gradle dependencies:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        applicationId "com.controladad.burgerhouse"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.IntruderShanky:Squint:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.6.0'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'com.alexzh:circleimageview:1.1.2@aar'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.4'
    compile 'com.azoft.carousellayoutmanager:carousel:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.polok:clicknumberpicker:0.1.2'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.ome450901:SimpleRatingBar:1.2'

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile  'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'
    //compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.2.2'

    compile 'com.desarrollodroide:fragmenttransactionextended:1'
    compile 'com.github.matrixxun:MaterialBadgeTextView:c5a27e8243'
    compile 'com.github.elevenetc:badgeview:v1.0.0'

    compile 'com.labo.kaji:fragmentanimations:0.1.1'
    compile 'com.yarolegovich:discrete-scrollview:1.2.0'

    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.yarolegovich:mp:1.0.5'

/*    //Use persian timepicker from this library
    compile 'com.mohamadamin:persianmaterialdatetimepicker:1.2.1'
    //Use persian datepicker form this library
    compile 'com.alirezaafkar:sundatepicker:2.0.8'*/
    compile project(path: ':PrsianDateTimePicker')
    compile 'com.cleveroad:fan-layout-manager:1.0.4'
}
```

could anybody help me to solve this problem? any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle error upgrading to Android Studio 3.0 Beta 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45597661/gradle-error-upgrading-to-android-studio-3-0-beta-1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace all your `compile` keywords with `implementation` or `api` respectively in your build.gradle.

Follow this to decide replacements: [Migrate to Android Plugin for Gradle 3.0.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations)

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will try that.

Comment: Could you please explain more about this, I have read the documentation but I'm a noobie about Gradle and its dependencies.

Comment: I have changed all the `compile` with `implementation` and then cleaned the project and Invalidate Caches/restart then the project started to work. thank you for your reply and help. if you have the time to explain what happens with this Gradle thing I will appreciate it.

Comment: Didn't work for me. AS 3.0-beta2, macOS 10.12, Kotlin project. All "compile" replaced with "implementation". Invalidated caches & restarted. Still the same issue.

Comment: Hm, I had to run ./gradlew clean also, and it worked.